# Will GC collect object if somebody holds a reference of it as interface?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have class `A` that implements interface `I` and pass it  somewhere where interface `I` is expected, for example to a thread, will this prevent GC from garbage collecting instance of class `A`? I think yes, but how should I work that out? Suppose create public static inner class?

Comment: It's a reference, it has nothing to do with what the referencing object is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked everything out with holding WeakReference to interface implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The *type* of reference to an object is immaterial here. It could be of the same type as object's, its super-type or an Interface. It doesn't matter at all.

What matters is whether an object is reachable from a *root context* or not. Till an object has a valid reference to it (irrespective of its reference's type) it won't get *garbage collected*.

In fact, the object may **not** even have a direct reference to it. It would still be ineligible for GC if it's reachable from the root context indirectly (tree traversal from GC roots) as explained below.

#### What is a Root Context?

All objects that your program creates at root i.e. directly like `Parent p = new Parent();` are called `GC Roots` and collectively they form the root context. None of the GC Roots are eligible for garbage collection. Now if you create a new `Child` object like

```
p.setChild(new Child());
```

then the `Child` object (although not a GC Root) becomes accessible from the root context via `Parent` p and hence is not eligible for garbage collection. Now, if you replace the current child as

```
p.setChild(new Child()); // old child replaced
```

the old child object becomes an *orphan* (not reachable from the root context anymore) and hence would get garbage collected. So, you can see that the reference type has no bearing on an object's garbage collection.

*And, just to be complete on this topic:* Islands of ***isolated*** objects (although they may hold references to each other) would still get garbage collected because they are unreachable from the root context.

Answer (score 3):

`Objects` becomes eligible for garbage collection..**Not references.** So you can say that an object becomes eligible for garbage collection if its all `references` are `terminated`.
.

Comment: It would be better to say "if all references to it cease to exist". A reference to an object can't become null; a variable containing a reference to an object can become null, but then it doesn't contain the reference any more, so it's not the case that the reference becomes null!

Comment: @TomAnderson true words !! edited.Thanks tom for the concern.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't garbage collect the instance because a reference to the object still exists in the thread stack.